# Fourier Transform for PDE $u_{xy}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

Using the Fourier transform, $\mathscr{F}\{\cdot\} = \hat{f}(\cdot)$, may I transform the $u_{xy}$ where $u=u(x,y,t)$, $x,y \in (-\infty, \infty)$ and $t \in (0,1]$? The initial condition is $u(x,y,t)=\delta(x) \delta(y)$ for $t=0$.

I tried the following:

$
\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{u_{xy}\}=\hat{f}(\xi_1, \xi_2)& =\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial^{2}{u}}      {\partial{x}\partial{y}} e^{-2 \pi i (\xi_1 x + \xi_2 y)} dx dy \tag{1} \\
& = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} e^{-2 \pi i \xi_2 y} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} e^{-2 \pi i \xi_1 x} dx\right) dy \tag{2} \\
& = 2 \pi i \xi_1 \hat{f}(\xi_1) \int_{\mathbb{R}} -2 \pi i \xi_2 e^{-2 \pi i \xi_2 y} dy \tag{3} \\
& = 4 \pi^{2} \xi_1 \hat{f}(\xi_1) \xi_2 \delta(\xi_2) \tag{4}
\end{align}
$

where in (2) I used [Leibniz rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html), in (3) differentiated the integrand w.r.t. $y$ and in (4) used the Fourier transform of $1$ referenced [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform1.html).

If this is so, then I can take the inverse of the transform to get the original function.

Edit:
The PDE is the following:

$
\begin{cases}
u_{t} = u_{xx} + 2 \rho u_{xy} + u_{yy}, \ & \text{for} \ t \in (0,1],\\
u(x,y,t) = \delta(x) \delta(y), \ & \text{for} \ t = 0
\end{cases}
$

where $\rho \in (-1, 1)$.

Thank you.

Comment: In your integral, integrate by parts to see what the result comes to be. I often find this the best way to determine whether there are any issues in the transform without appealing to measure theoretic ideas.

Comment: @Mattos I showed my work of the Fourier transform. I'm not sure if it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: What is the PDE?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I edited and typed in the PDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\widehat u(\xi,\eta,t)$ be the Fourier transform (in the spatial variables) of $u(x,y,t)$. Each time you derivate $u$ with respect to $x$ you multiply $\widehat u$ by $-2\,\pi\,\xi\,i$; each time you derivate $u$ with respect to $y$ you multiply $\widehat u$ by $-2\,\pi\,\eta\,i$. Taking Fourier transforms in the equation we get then
$$
\frac{d\widehat u}{dt}=-4\,\pi^2\bigl(\xi^2+2\,\rho\,\xi\,\eta+\eta^2\bigr)\widehat u.
$$
This is first order linear ODE, which must be complemented with the initial condition
$$
\widehat u(\xi,\eta,0)=\mathcal{F}(\delta(x)\,\delta(y))=1.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I worked it out and checks. Thus, since we have the Fourier transform of the above PDE, we can take the inverse Fourier transform to find $u(x,y,t)$.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to procede.